# Remove white spaces in scala-spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have sample file record like this

```
2018-01-1509.05.540000000000001000000751111EMAIL@AAA.BB.CL
```

and the above record is from a fixed length file and I wanted to split based on the lengths

and when I split I am getting a list as shown below.

```
ListBuffer(2018-01-15, 09.05.54, 00000000000010000007, 5, 1111, EMAIL@AAA.BB.CL)
```

Everything looks fine until now . But I am not sure why is there extra-space adding in each field in the list(not for the first field).

Example : My data is "09.05.54",But I am getting as" 09.05.54" in the list.

My Logic for splitting is shown below

```
 // Logic to Split the Line based on the lengths
  def splitLineBasedOnLengths(line: String, lengths: List[String]): ListBuffer[Any] = {
    var splittedLine = line
    var split = new ListBuffer[Any]()
    for (i <- lengths) yield {
      var c = i.toInt
      var fi = splittedLine.take(c)
      split += fi
      splittedLine = splittedLine.drop(c)
    }
    split
  }
```

The above code take's the line and `list[String]` which are nothing but lengths  as input and gives the `listbuffer[Any]` which has the lines split according to the length.

Can any one help me why am I getting extra space before each field after splitting ?

Comment: What the length parameter contains ? can you please add sample for length?

Comment: There is no issue here. This is just how `toString` for `ListBuffer` is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There are no extra spaces in the data.  It's just adding some separation between the elements when printing them (using `toString`) to make them easier to read.

To prove this try the following code:

```
split.foreach(s => println(s"\"$s\""))
```

You will see the following printed:

```
"2018-01-15"
"09.05.54"
"00000000000010000007"
"5"
"1111"
"EMAIL@AAA.BB.CL"
```